# Add a value to the end of a pandas index object

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas index object and I'd like to add a single value to the end of it. The .append() method doesn't seem to work like one would expect, and since I'm trying to add an element, I can't insert at the location of -1 because that puts the value in the second-to-last position. For example

```
import pandas as pd
ser = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5], index=[11,12,13,14,15])
indx = ser.index
```

Say I want to add the value 20 to the end of the index. This throws an error:

```
indx.append(20)
```

This returns [11,12,13,14,20,15]:

```
indx.insert(-1, 20)
```

This works but seems like a work-around:

```
indx.insert(len(indx), 20)
```

Is there something I'm missing? This is on pandas 0.18.1. Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to pass a collection of index values as parameter while appending to the given `index` object.

```
indx.append(pd.Index([20]))   # Pass the values inside the list 
Int64Index([11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 20], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: `Int64Index` has been deprecated since v1.4.0 (2022) and will be removed in future v2.0. See [Int64Index](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Int64Index.html)

Answer (score 16):

The method `append` takes another index as input, but [`union`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#combining-joining-set-operations) will work if you simply pass an array-like object:

```
indx.union([20])
```

Note that index objects in pandas are immutable, so any such operation will return a new index rather than modifying the existing one.

Comment: I like this one because it's shorter than creating a new Index to append but turned out the new values were added the the beginning instead of the end.

Comment: This method does not preserve the order of the values in the index.

Comment: This does not [append](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.append.html), rather it does a [union](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.union.html).

Comment: This solution works great, just pass `sort=False` to to preserve ordering: `indx.union([20], sort=False)`.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to try these two options:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
ser.append(pd.Series([np.nan], index = [20]))

# 11    1.0
# 12    2.0
# 13    3.0
# 14    4.0
# 15    5.0
# 20    NaN
# dtype: float64

ser.set_value(20, np.nan)

# 11    1.0
# 12    2.0
# 13    3.0
# 14    4.0
# 15    5.0
# 20    NaN
# dtype: float64
```

Comment: If your goal was to expand the series rather than the index itself, you should go with this answer.